# Rotten eggs smell in house

Tags: plumbing

We bought a 3rd floor apartment in Italy (highest floor) a few years ago and use it as a holiday home. We've had no issues for about 3 years and suddenly we started getting the smell of rotten eggs at the entrance to the apartment. We've got someone coming in regularly and ensuring the water traps are full every week. The smell just doesn't seem to go and peaks at about 4am in the morning. I can't localise it to any bathroom or the kitchen or the HVAC system. we've had an army of plumbers come and go and no one seems to have a solution. As mentioned the smell is at it's worst at the entrance to the apartment and maybe this is because we detect it coming in from outside the house. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Something hidden and rotting?

Answer (score 2):

Some people describe the smell of the additive that they put in natural gas as a "rotten eggs smell". I am not sure if they use such additive in natural gas in Italy but if so then you may want to consider that this smell is the accumulated gas from a gas leak someplace.